# Typeface is not rendered in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to set a font like this:

```
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/myfont.ttf");
    textView.setTypeFace(tf);
```

However, it works for some fonts like Helvetica, or like that, but as soon as I try to load some other fonts, it ignores my typeface and it loads android's default one.

I've checked a looot of answers, and an user stated

> Android at the moment when can't set a typeface, instead of throwing an exception, just places system default typeface.

But this is obviously not an answer.

What can I do?

I've even checked sourcecode of `TextView`, which leaded me to `TextPaint`, and `TextPaint` leaded me to `Paint` but couldn't really find a solution about my issue.

Help would be sooo appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: could you check if thre is no style added in the xml ?

Comment: Post your layout code of TextView.

Comment: @GrIsHu Textview tv = new TextView(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this is obviously not an answer.

Well, grammatically it has issues, but it *is* the answer. Android has had problems loading fonts since Android 1.0, and the API for `Typeface` does not report success or failure.

> What can I do?

Test your typefaces and see which ones work.

If you have licensed the rights to modify the font, you could try loading it into a font editor and saving it again, to see if it is a question of the format of the font file.

Or, contribute changes to the [AOSP](http://source.android.com) to improve typeface handling, then wait a few years for those changes to make it out to the majority of Android devices.

Comment: I've edited the font and removed characters that weren't used, some weird ascii, but anyways it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try typeface using `SpannableStringBuilder` it will work,,

```
String stringResult="Your unicode string";
            SpannableStringBuilder SS = new SpannableStringBuilder(stringResult);
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/myfont.ttf");
            if(tf != null)
            {
                    SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("", tf), 0, stringResult.length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            }

            textView.setText(SS);
```